# Android: how can I identify a button while using a double array?

Tags: java, android

I have this code for creating a 10x10 grid of buttons:

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {                                          
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j=0; j<=9; j++) {                                      
            Button button = new Button (this);
            button.setHeight(30);
            button.setWidth(30);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
            tr.addView(button, 30,30);

            if (bommaker[i][j]) {
                isBomb = true;
            } else {
                isBomb = false;
            }

            veld[i][j] = new Vakje(isBomb);

        }
        layout.addView(tr);
    }
```

It also adds a new "Vakje" per button created. "Vakje" is a different class of course.

Now my question: how can I be able to indentify which button is pressed, so I can call methods from the class "Vakje" within the onClick() method.
For example, I can't just add the "i" and "j" variables as parameters to button.setOnClickListener(this).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) and create a new onClickListener for each button

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {                                          
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    for (int j=0; j<=9; j++) {                                      
        Button button = new Button (this);
        button.setHeight(30);
        button.setWidth(30);

        button.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        tr.addView(button, 30,30);

        if (bommaker[i][j]) {
            isBomb = true;
        } else {
            isBomb = false;
        }
        final Vakje vakjeObject = new Vakje(isBomb);
        //veld[i][j] = new Vakje(isBomb);
        button.setOnClickListener( new onClickListener() 
        {
          public void onClick(View v) {
           vakjeObject.yourMethod();
          }
        });

    }
    layout.addView(tr);
}
```

I haven't compiled it so I don't know if there are errors, but this should give you the general idea

Answer (score 0):

You could set the id of the button to i and j via the setId() method once you have created the button.

I.e. button.setId(ij);

then in the onClick() method you could use the id to retrieve the correct Vakje object.

Comment: This is a good one, only the setId() wont accept two integers.

Comment: Combine the two integers into one. best to stitch the two together. I.e. if i is 1 and j is 2 then the id could be 12. Makes it easy to figure out which object to get. You would just need to separate them in the onClick() method.